# Help finding the sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The series;

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=9}( \frac{3}{(k-1)^2}-\frac{3}{k^2})$

I managed to reduce it down to

$\frac{6k^4-3k^3}{k^4-2k^3+k^2}$

Doing the comparison test I found that the series converges (the limit was equal to 6), but I'm having trouble finding what the series converges **to**.

If it helps, this is in a first year Analysis class.

Comment: Doesn't the series telescope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a telescoping series. Its sum is equal to $\dfrac3{(9-1)^2}=\dfrac3{64}$.

Comment: How do I spot that it telescopes?

Comment: It's of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^\infty(a_{k-1}-a_k)$.

Comment: @Karl Coogan Even writing the first few terms helps: $\dfrac{3}{64}-\dfrac{3}{81}+\dfrac{3}{81}-\dfrac{3}{100}+\dfrac{3}{100}-\dots$. Notice how every term after $\dfrac{3}{64}$ gets cancelled.